# Has there ever been an approved viral infection treatment method based on the physical/mechanical properties of virus?

Tags: virology, infection, treatment

I imagined that typical cells and viruses could have very different physical properties or reactions to mechanical stresses, which makes selective targetting possible. For instance, some  major differences between viruses and animal cells:

1. Difference in size/mass
2. Difference in elasticity (lack of cytosol in virus)
3. Difference in structural composition results in a different reaction in response to different vibrational frequencies

Preliminary search found something related to [microwave absorption induced oscillation mode fracturing airborne virus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4673452/), taking advantage of the (structural) core-shell charge separation in virus (not sure if I described the principle right, to be honest). However, though looks exciting, it is more like a disinfection rather than a treatment method. So the question goes: Has there ever been an approved viral infection treatment method based on the physical/mechanical properties of virus?